# Regarding applying for British Army

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, uk-citizens, foreign-employment, uk-visitor-visa

I am an Indian citizen and i have never visited/resided in Britain, also I haven't acquired passport yet.
I want to apply for British Army as a Commonwealth Country's citizen but in the application form it's asking me for Date of entry into the UK?
Although I have chosen the option of not having passport right now.
So, which date should i enter into it?
Should i proceed to apply before getting passport?
Or if anyone knows its process then please let me know[image]

Comment: Do you mean the Army application form https://apply.army.mod.uk/how-to-join/joining-process/soldier-recruitment-steps  or the visitor visa application? If the former, can you post a screen shot of the section of the application form to which you’re referring? If the latter, I’d think the date refers to your attendance at the 2 day Assessment Centre in the UK.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of army application of which my question is all about

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right form to apply from outside the UK and have filled in the questions up to this point correctly? Why have you answered ‘Indian’ to the question about which passport you used to enter the UK if a) you’re not in the UK now; b) you don’t have a passport; c) you’ve never visited the UK?

Comment: More, why did you declare in the form that you entered the UK on 30/4/2019 when you've told us you've never entered the UK?

Comment: Yes sir i am filling the correct form but the issue is they asked me about passport and because I am an Indian citizen so it's obvious that I would enter UK in future with Indian passport only, I have chosen that I don't have passport so it's obvious that I wouldn't have visited to UK then I don't know why they're further asking which passport I used to enter UK and also the date of entering

Comment: @Baz But the question is ‘which passport did you use’ (past tense) not ‘will you use’ (future tense). It implies you are in the UK. Is there a N/A or leave blank option? If not, my guess is you’ve either selected the wrong form or answered a previous question incorrectly. If you can’t see anything wrong with your choices then I suggest you contact the Army applications help team.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that you’re using the wrong application form  and/or you have filled in some information incorrectly.  The question ‘which passport did you use to enter the UK’ implies you are in the UK, whereas you state in your question that you’ve never entered the UK.

If you’re sure that

- you’ve selected the right form to apply from outside the UK
- there isn’t a N/A or leave blank option for the question
- you can’t see anything wrong with the way you’ve completed the form up to this point

I suggest you contact the Army applications help team.